# How do I make vim syntax highlight a whole line?

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, line, highlighting

I'd like to have vim highlight entire lines that match certain patterns.  I can get all the text in a line to highlight (by doing `syn match MyMatch "^.*text-to-match.*$"`), but it always stops at the end of the text.  I'd like to to continue to the end of the term, like highlighting CursorLine.

I've tried replacing `$` with a `\n^`, hoping that would wrap it around.  No change.  (I didn't actually expect this would work, but there's no harm in trying.)  I also tried adjusting the syn-pattern-offset (which I read about here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-pattern).  Long story short, adding `he=he-5` will highlight 5 fewer characters, but `he=he+5` doesn't show any extra characters because there aren't characters to highlight.

This is my first attempt at making a vim syntax and I'm relatively new to vim.  Please be gentle and include explanations.

Thanks!

(edit: Forgot to include, this is a multiline highlight.  That probably increases the complexity a bit.)

Comment: Is your pattern supposed to read `^.*text-to-match.*$`?

Comment: Jefromi, it is.  SO apparently uses wrapped asterisks to do italics.  It's fixed now.

Comment: No other syntaxes, but it's entirely possible the rest of my syntax is bludgeoning itself.  Maybe I should start from the lines I want to fully highlight and then write the rest once that's working?

Comment: Oh, I totally read "whole line" as "whole line of text". I suspect there's in fact no way to do this.

Comment: was looking for the same thing, and actually it works for me by leaving out the ^ and $

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation on `syn-pattern`:

> The highlighted area will never be
>   outside of the matched text.

I'd count myself surprised if you got this to work, but then again, Vim is always full of surprises.

Comment: Yes, but the pattern is matching the entire line. It should highlight the entire line.

Comment: If the window is 80 characters, and the text is 4 characters, only the 4 characters are matched and only the 4 characters are highlighted. The OP wants all 80 columns highlighted.

Comment: Jay's correct.  There's no way to mimic the behavior of the `cursorline` option with standard syntax highlighting.  Syntax highlighting is simply meant to highlight existing text.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but also explains why I wasn't able to figure it out :-P

Answer (score 15):

It's not very adaptive as the filename (buffer) and line to full row highlight needs to be explicitly identified, but apparently the **[sign](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html)** command can be used:

> It is possible to highlight an entire
>   line using the **:sign** mechanism.
>   An example can be found at `:help
>   sign-commands`
>   In a nutshell:

```
:sign define wholeline linehl=ErrorMsg
:sign place 1 name=wholeline line=123 file=thisfile.txt
```

> Obviously, you should pick a higlight
>   group that changes the color of the
>   background for the linehl argument.

source: [Erik Falor, vim mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/77250/focus=77311)

Comment: You can background-highlight the whole line this way but the text will lose its syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

could also try
        :set cursorline
        :set cursorcolumn
change colors like this:
        :hi cursorline
        :hi cursorcolumn
using the usual term=, ctermfg=, ctermbg= etc
see this answer
[VIM Highlight the whole current line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750792/vim-highlight-the-whole-current-line)