# Highlight the whole current line

Tags: vim, navigation, highlight

What is the best way to highlight the whole current line in Vim? In some IDEs I am able to set some sort of 20% opacity of the line I am editing, this is great to find where I am rather quickly.

Comment: Related: [vimrc - How can I change the colour of the line highlighted with the 'cursorline' option? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/how-can-i-change-the-colour-of-the-line-highlighted-with-the-cursorline-option)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To highlight the current line use

```
:set cursorline
```

To highlight the current column use

```
:set cursorcolumn
```

The visual appearance of this can be modified. Have a look around `:help hl-CursorLine` or `hl-CursorColumn`.

Answer (score 17):

See [the Vim wiki on this subject](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line) for the complete story.

I especially found the following bit handy (when working with more than one window).

```
autocmd WinEnter * setlocal cursorline
autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

Only highlight the current line in the active window.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> puts you in *visual mode*, highlighting the entire line.

Comment: It makes sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This enters Vim in Visual Mode though. When you are going to move to another line, the lines in between will be highlighted as well.