# Setting Vim cursorline colors?

Tags: vim

I have tried to look at other answers here on SO and Google but none of them seem to be changing my cursor settings. I am wanting to have a background of yellow with foreground of white bold but can't get it with the settings that I have seen around the web. I am using MacVim mvim in iTerm2.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM Highlight the whole current line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750792/vim-highlight-the-whole-current-line)

Comment: Not a duplicate. @pertrai1 is already using the options, as can be seen on the screenthot.

Comment: @JeffBridgman - No, if you look at my screenshot I already have those set that are answered in the possible duplicate

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most likely you are interested in these three highlighting groups: `Cursor`, `CursorColumn` and `CursorLine`. The names are self explanatory.

For example to change just the cursor color:

```
:highlight Cursor ctermfg=White ctermbg=Yellow cterm=bold guifg=white guibg=yellow gui=bold
```

To do the same for column cursor:

```
:highlight CursorColumn ctermfg=White ctermbg=Yellow cterm=bold guifg=white guibg=yellow gui=bold
```

If you also need to highlight the current line, use  `CursorLine`.

Comment: sorry for the beginner part of me asking this question: how would I set this in my .vimrc file? When i did it in normal mode it worked great, but I want it to stay like that all the time. Thank you for bearing with me on this.

Comment: Copy paste them to `.vimrc` without the leading `:`.

Answer (score 12):

If you wants to keep it enable always put the below things in your .vimrc or .gvimrc file

for cursorline

```
set cursorline
autocmd InsertEnter * highlight CursorLine guibg=#000050 guifg=fg
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight CursorLine guibg=#004000 guifg=fg
```

for cursor column

```
set cursorcolumn
autocmd InsertEnter * highlight CursorColumn ctermfg=White ctermbg=Yellow cterm=bold guifg=white guibg=yellow gui=bold
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight CursorColumn ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Yellow cterm=bold guifg=Black guibg=yellow gui=NONE
```

You can change the colors in your wish